# Ways to reduce SASS changeset between developers

Tags: css, git, sass, gulp

I'm working on a site that uses Gulp to compile its SASS, among other things. It was set up by another developer on my team. I am brand new to Gulp and don't use SASS much either. However, getting it up and running was easy.

The one problem, though, is that when I ran Gulp, even though I hadn't changed anything in the source files, it changed pretty much every generated CSS file in the project. Every file had `/*! typey | GPLv2 License | https://github.com/jptaranto/typey */` added at the top, and there were many files where numeric values changed by a tiny bit (like `skewX(0.39063deg)` → `skewX(0.39062deg)`). And it also added hundreds of *.map files which didn't exist before.

This has happened to me before using Compass too. It pretty much makes looking at the diff useless to see any actual changes. Is there a way to unify the output of our Gulp so this doesn't happen?

Comment: Are you committing generated output? Why do you need to do that? Can't you simply regenerate them when needed anyway?

Comment: I think the reason is that when we deploy, it's just via a pull from Bitbucket, so the CSS files need to be there.